# HTML-Bootstrap: How to make collapsible text appear under its own button

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to use collapsible text.
I am using two button for collapsing and their corresponding collapsible text.
The problem is the text is appearing at the end of the buttons instead of appearing after their respective buttons.

Here is what I am trying to do when clicking the buttons (text to appear below its button):

```
------------  
| Button-1 |  
------------  
Text for Button-1  

------------  
| Button-2 |  
------------  
Text for Button-2
```

But here is what I am getting:

```
------------  
| Button-1 |  
------------  
------------  
| Button-2 |  
------------  
Text for Button-1
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
<h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text1">Button-1</button><br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text2">Button-2</button>
  <div id="text1" class="collapse">
   This text should appear under Button-1
  </div>
  <div id="text2" class="collapse">
   Text to appear under Button-2
  </div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why cant you just move the `collapse` divs under there corresponding buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Simply moving the `div`s should fix your issue

```
<h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text1">Button-1</button>
<div id="text1" class="collapse">
    This text should appear under Button-1
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text2">Button-2</button>
<div id="text2" class="collapse">
    Text to appear under Button-2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text1">Button-1</button><br/>
<div id="text1" class="collapse">
   This text should appear under Button-1
  </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text2">Button-2</button>
  <div id="text2" class="collapse">
   Text to appear under Button-2
  </div>
```